# while loop stops too late with eof check

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, fstream, eof

I have to read a file that contains a list of paths which are stored in a vector.

```
    vector<string> files;
    ifstream in;
    string x;

    while( !in.eof() ) {
       in >> x;
       files.push_back(x);
    }
```

but the problem is that when the last path is read in.eof() is still false and the loop continue for another unwanted step.
A fix could be a thing like this

```
    vector<string> files;
    ifstream in;
    string x;

    while( in >> x ) {
       files.push_back(x);
    }
```

but I think that isn't a great solution in the case of a more complex code in the while loop. Am I wrong?

Comment: the solution you posted is fine. Another way to do this would be to check the length of string x and stop if its empty.

Comment: Yes, you're wrong. The latter code is exactly right.

Comment: Read more about the "EOF anti-pattern" here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941 and http://drpaulcarter.com/cs/common-c-errors.php#4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will allow you to read to the end of the file and no further. As long as the file has text in it, this will read each line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
 string line;
 ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
 if (myfile.is_open())
 {
   while ( getline (myfile,line) )
   {
     cout << line << '\n';
   }
   myfile.close();
 }

 else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

 return 0;
}
```